# Microsoft Search Server: The OLEDB Driver is not installed with server?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am unable to connect to the Search Server OLE DB provider.

Search Server itself is up and running and making indexes happily. Search Server 2010 on Win 2012, x64 system

I am fighting this error: "The 'Search.CollatorDSO' provider is not registered on the local machine. "

Below is a picture showing:

a) The error I get in a simple sql query tool (from codeplex)

b) A powershell query to list available ole db providers.... indicating that the provider for search server is not present on the system.

fwiw, I believe the SQL Query tool may be 32 bit. System is x64.

[image: Picture showing the setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Downloading and installing Windows Search Server 2010 installs a ton of server pieces, but does **not install the OLE DB driver**.

The way to get the ole db driver is to enable this on Server 2012 "Windows Search Service" (believe it is on by default on Win7 and 8)

[image]